# Contour Expression help: Return latest row entry date grouped by customer ID from multiple customers and rows

Tags: partition

Having trouble writting an expression that will return the latest entry grouped by a customer ID

sample data
Customer  Entry    Date
cust1     123      1
Cust1     456      2
Cust2     789      3

Result Should be
Customer  Entry   Date
Cust1     456     2
Cust2     789     3

Tried:
max(date) over (
Partition by customer
)

A few other things but none successful